# I keep having this error with nested for loops

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Insérer entier inférieur à 100"))
prime = []
if 100 >= n > 1 :
    for number in range(2, n+1):
        for div in range(number, 2):

            if number % div == 0 :

                prime.append(number)
```

i want it to, if it's prime, add itself in the prime list ig ?
please help me im struggling it's for a school project, thank you

Comment: I see you've posted some python code.  How is it going? Does it run? Are there any errors?

Comment: `for div in range(number, 2)` looks wrong - this is iterating from `number` to `2`, but what you want to be doing _might_ be the opposite, `range(2, number)`

Comment: A [MCVE] is more than just the code (though I'll note, this isn't even a [MCVE] on the code, since it has no output to check). It's example inputs, expected outputs, and observed behavior (including tracebacks if needed).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have the condition for inner loop, it should be `range(2, number)` instead of `range(number, 2)`.

Furthermore, you are not checking the number for prime correctly. Currently, if it checks whether 24 is prime or not, then, it will add 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 and 12 to the list - which is wrong.
To check whether a number is prime or not, you can check whether it is divisible by any previous number or not. If it is prime, then add it to the list.

The corrected code will be:

```py
n = int(input("Insérer entier inférieur à 100"))
primes = []
if 100 >= n:  # second condition is unnecessory
    for number in range(2, n+1):
        for div in range(2, number):  # update the range
            if number % div == 0 :
                break
        else:       # if it is prime, add to list
            # This is only reached if we did not use break
            primes.append(number)
print(primes)
```